# Extract mapAsync to method in AkkaStreams

Tags: dictionary, methods, akka, akka-stream

I have an Akka Streams flow, at one point I need to use mapAsync with a block of code.

```
    (...)
    .via(flow1)
    .mapAsync(1)(response => 
     * Several linees of code her*
    )
    .via(flow2)
```

Is there a cleaner way of extracting it into a method?

```
    (...)
    .via(flow1)
    .doComputations
    .via(flow2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new flow

```
val asyncProc = Flow[T].mapAsync(1) { response => 
// Several lines of code here
}
```

and use it with `via`

```
flow1
  .via(asyncProc)
  .via(flow2)
```